# Rufus corrupted my usb drive with windows 8.1 boot image

Tags: windows, bootable-media

I used rufus to create a bootable usb drive for windows 8.1 image. After ejecting the drive and plugging it back, the usb was not detected in windows. I tried everything that is available on internet, partition tool, diskpart etc. Its not detected even in diskpart.

Any tip on recovering my usb drive?

Comment: Its likely your flash drive has burnt. Sorry to say that but can you check it on other's computers? Check it and let us know. If it worked on them, then it seems your motherboard has a problem with it. at that time my best suggestion is use a BOOTABLE partitioning tool. Like paragon (I dont know it is copyrighted or not but I have it! but it should be free like other bootable softwares.). Also try HIREN boot CD.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I checked in different systems, no luck with  that either. Looks like the drive is dead now.